# compiling issue related to slf4j library

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j, mahout

I am trying to compile an open source library, and meet the following problem. When I keep the two libraries, slf4j-jcl-1.6.0.jar and slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar, the eclipse compiler will give me the following error messages:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/chengs6/mahout/mahout-distribution-0.5/mahout-examples-0.5-job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/chengs6/mahout/mahout-distribution-0.5/lib/slf4j-jcl-1.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

If I remove these two libraries, then the compiler will give me the following error messages:

> Jun 15, 2011 2:51:12 PM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter error

How to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLF4J only requires you to have `slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar` and one of the logger implementations in your classpath. This is what the [manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) says:

> Note that SLF4J-enabling your
>   library/application implies the
>   addition of only a single mandatory
>   dependency, namely
>   `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar`.

In your case I'd guess you have [multiple logger implementations in your classpath](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings). It looks to me like `mahout-examples-0.5-job.jar` already includes some SLF4J implementation classes.